# Override bundle class silex authentification php

Tags: php, silex

Here I began with Silex and I do not understand how to override a class.

I use a plugin to manage authentication.
Everything works, however I would like to change the checkPreAuth () method to verify the account from the user before authentication without change yhe bundle code.
To do this I made the steps below:

I created a class UserDAO to call the plugin which extends the native class.

But it doesn't work because I make a simple die('foo !') in the new method in UserDAO but apparently my method is not taken into account because the die('foo !') doesn't appear :-(  someone there to help me :-)

Class UserDAO:

```
use MicroCMS\Domain\User;

use MicroCMS\PDO\PDOController as PDOController;

use PDO;

class UserDAO extends BaseUserChecker implements UserProviderInterface
{
     public function __construct() {

     }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user){
    die('je rentre dans cette fonction !');
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user){

    }

}
```

thanks in advance